# Rollup Q&A: How do you update a SORU? From L1 protocol update, from an admin key/multisig/governance, releasing another rollup and migrate?

Tags: governance, smart-rollup, rollup

[Question from reddit]

> How do you update a SORUs (update the SORUs settings for example)? Do
> you need a L1 protocol update? Do you have an admin key with full
> power? Or do you release another rollup and ask users to migrate to
> the new rollup, like defi protocols do?

Answer (score 0):

Response from whalesniper

> Both/Either. You can spread code across multiple rollups to make one
> big kernel, so I'm sure you can implement upgrading logic. As long as
> it's known beforehand (or handled by a DAO), I see little issue with
> it.

Response from daniel hines

> Rollup kernels can modify their own code. See the installer kernel for
> an example.
>
> How this plays out is under the control of the SORU kernel developer.
> Personally I would want upgrades to a rollup I used to be protected by
> multisig and time delay!

Answer from Nomadic labs

> It depends on how the rollup is configured when deployed. Both rollups
> with admin keys and 100% trustless rollups are possible on Tezos.
> There is a special location in the durable storage of the WASM PVM
> where the kernel – the DApp code – is located. It is up to the DApp
> logic to implement an update mechanism by modifying this location and
> by rebooting the WASM machine. See the “installer kernel” that works
> following this principle:
> https://gitlab.com/tezos/kernel/-/blob/main/installer_kernel/src/reveal_installer.rs